Solving PDE using Lagrange's equation and multipliers such that the numerator is differential of the denominator
The given PDE is $$y^2(x-y)p+x^2(y-x)q=z(x^2+y^2)$$
I know that the the lagrange equation will be
$$\frac{dx}{y^2(x-y)}=\frac{dy}{x^2(y-x)}=\frac{dz}{z(x^2+y^2)}$$
And that the solution will be $F(u,v)=0$ where u,v are solutions of ODEs formed from the lagrange equation.
Using the first two fracs, I get $u=x^3+y^3$ which is correct.
For v, our instructor told us to use multipliers P, Q, R to form
$$\frac{Pdx+Qdy+Rdz}{Py^2(x-y)+Qx^2(y-x)+Rz(x^2+y^2)}$$
Where the numerator of this equation should be the differential of the denomator. We need to then find other similar multipliers to form independent terms which can be used to form an ODE which can be solved to find v.
I am struggling in determining these multipliers. I have no idea how to determine them and am just guessing and seeing if it works. Can someone explain how to approach such an issue? Any help will be appreciated.
The answer for the PDE is
$$F(x^3+y^3,(x-y)/z) =0$$

Notice that
$$
\frac{dx}{y^2(x-y)}=\frac{dy}{x^2(y-x)}=\frac{dx-dy}{(y^2+x^2)(x-y)}=
\frac{d(x-y)}{(x^2+y^2)(x-y)}, \tag{1}
$$
hence
$$
\frac{dz}{z(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{d(x-y)}{(x^2+y^2)(x-y)}
\implies \frac{dz}{z}=\frac{d(x-y)}{x-y} 
$$
$$
\implies z=C(x-y). \tag{2}
$$
Defining $v=\frac{1}{C}=\frac{x-y}{z}$, you obtain the desired result.

Hi, I understand the explanation, but can you explain how you approached this question. Like how did you notice (1)

Trial and error. (But knowing the expected result --- your last equation --- was a good guide.)
